# Hypothetically speaking, Stock Price won't change in case there is no Volume?

Tags: stocks, stock-valuation

**Hypothetically speaking**, let's say there is no trading volume during 1 year for a given stock, does that mean the stock price will remain the same regardless of how the company is performing?

*Let me emphasize the word "Hypothetically", because I know it is unrealistic. I just would like to know if Supply and Demand is the only rule applied when it comes to stock price.*

Comment: 'Stock Price' is literally just the last traded price. No trades = no price to update, it would remain as is.

Comment: Indeed, quite simply there is no "price" for a stock, it is a meaningless idea.  Imagine a house for sale on your street ... #123 Smith Street. What is the "price" of the house, you tell me ?  All you can really say is "well the last time it was sold, it was $220,000".  That's it.  Houses and stock have no "price".

Comment: I would like to thank everyone that answered the question and those who marked the question as a duplicated as well. Everything was using, thank you !!

Answer (score -1):

The bid and the ask price might vary.  The current price or closing price would be the last trade - which occurred a year ago - and it would not change unless there was a hypothetical dividend (regular or special) or a hypothetical stock split (standard or reverse).

Comment: Even if there was a dividend, if there is no sale the last traded price would not change.

Comment: @Victor Stock exchanges reduce share price by the exact amount of the dividend on the ex-dividend date so the previous close (last trade) is adjusted  down in price by that amount.  For example, the closing price of HAS was $87.36 on 4/27.  Today (4/30) it went  ex-div for 63 cents.  No trades have occurred and the adjusted close is now $86.73 in the pre-market.  So while the last trade was at a higher price, the closing price is now lower than it was on Friday.

Comment: @BobBaerker: I could've sworn *the market* reduces the share price. That is, people decide to pay less for the stock based on the reduction in value. Looking at a price chart doesn't dispel that illusion; the price drops are more gradual than if the exchange did it unilaterally.

Comment: @Chao  Look up what stocks are going ex-dividend tomorrow.  Note the amount of the dividend as well as today's closing prices for those stocks.  Then check the closing price  of those shares tomorrow morning before and trading occurs.  You will see an adjusted close which is today's close minus the amount of the dividend.  That is done by the exchanges not through some group think of investors.  This process also explains why a dividend  does not provide Total Return.